# How can I show information about a group of values ​from different rows that correspond to a specific value? All this based on an equality condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I will greatly appreciate your support.

I have the following table in oracle

| User_id | User | Department | id_depto | id_manage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 165 | Jhonson | Purchasing management | 900 | 900 |
| 356 | David | purchasing department R1 | 343 | 900 |
| 545 | Mary | purchasing department R2 | 326 | 900 |
| 825 | Alexander | Finance department | 925 | 800 |

I would like to receive the data in the following way, when id_depto=id_manage is met

receive n records with the data of the user that meets the equality condition by only changing the id_depto corresponding to the id_manage group.

| User_id | User | Department | id_depto | id_manage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 165 | Jhonson | Purchasing management | 900 | 900 |
| 165 | Jhonson | Purchasing management | 343 | 900 |
| 165 | Jhonson | Purchasing management | 326 | 900 |
| 356 | David | purchasing department R1 | 343 | 900 |
| 545 | Mary | purchasing department R2 | 326 | 900 |
| 825 | Alexander | Finance department | 925 | 800 |

is this possible? thanks for your help. greetings.

I have looked for ways in which I can apply the query but I cannot find clear information

Comment: Hi - if your formatted your data as tables then all the columns would line up and make it much easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```sql
select *
from t
union all
select x.user_id, x.usr, x.department, t.id_depto, t.id_manage
from t
join t x on x.id_depto = x.id_manage 
        and x.id_depto = t.id_manage 
        and x.user_id <> t.user_id
order by 1
```

Result:

```
 USER_ID  USR        DEPARTMENT                ID_DEPTO  ID_MANAGE 
 -------- ---------- ------------------------- --------- --------- 
 165      Jhonson    Purchasing management     900       900       
 165      Jhonson    Purchasing management     326       900       
 165      Jhonson    Purchasing management     343       900       
 356      David      purchasing department R1  343       900       
 545      Mary       purchasing department R2  326       900       
 825      Alexander  Finance department        925       800
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eDfvOKbt).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to receive the data in the following way, when `id_depto=id_manage` is met
>
> receive n records with the data of the user that meets the equality condition by only changing the id_depto corresponding to the id_manage group.

The logic is not particularly well explained but you appear to want to use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT user_id AS user_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT user_name AS user_name,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT department AS department,
       id_depto,
       id_manage
FROM   table_name
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR id_depto = id_manage;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(User_id, User_name,  Department, id_depto, id_manage) AS
SELECT 165, 'Jhonson',   'Purchasing management',    900, 900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 356, 'David',     'purchasing department R1', 343, 900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 545, 'Mary',      'purchasing department R2', 326, 900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 825, 'Alexander', 'Finance department',       925, 800 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | DEPARTMENT | ID_DEPTO | ID_MANAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 825 | Alexander | Finance department | 925 | 800 |
| 165 | Jhonson | Purchasing management | 900 | 900 |
| 165 | Jhonson | Purchasing management | 343 | 900 |
| 165 | Jhonson | Purchasing management | 326 | 900 |
| 356 | David | purchasing department R1 | 343 | 900 |
| 545 | Mary | purchasing department R2 | 326 | 900 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rm5DcF07)

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, another way in which I obtained the expected result!